# Error on installing Visual Studio 2013 Pro/Community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I was trying to install VS 2013 and got errors on both Community and Pro editions, internet installer and .ISO installer, respectively.

All the time, during the installation, I get a message that the installation failed because "MS Build Tools x86 " can't be installed.

I tried download and install a standalone Build Tools x86, but after some time of installation it aborts saying that "Build Tools x86 can't be installed cause Build Tools x86 couldn't be installed" ( lol ).

I'm under Win 8.1 , Core i7, 8 Gb Ram...tried several times.

Any help would be so good. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who experiencied such a problem, the solution was unregister/register MSI .

In other words, the problem was in the Windows Installer, not in my SO or Build Tools neither the VS versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem after trying to uninstall and install to an SSD as a secondary drive.

Check your logs in:

'C:\Users\DonB\AppData\Local\Temp'

If there is a version mismatch on the build-tool use the Microsoft tool to [remove](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/program_install_and_uninstall) all iterations of the build tools.

Then try and install again. If the problem persists follow the below steps:

Un-install VS 2013 and clear out the below folders:

'C:\Users[WindowsUser]\AppData\Local\Temp'

'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache' (Not really recommended, only if nothing else works)

I [ran](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833) a 'sfc /scannow' from an elevated shell just to be sure. ()